# drop external table hangs

Tags: oracle, external-tables

Oracle 9.2.0.1

T1 is an external table accessed through a cursor from another database by using database link

I give command

```
drop table T1;
```

which time outs with ORA-4021

Comment: Is the other database actively accessing the table over the link? Can you [close the database link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-a-distributed-database.html#GUID-AF6B5F62-0180-4F8F-A5F0-05246A750CB2) from the remote DB and see if that clears the block?

Comment: @AlexPoole the remote session is closed

Comment: You can [query the performance views](http://psoug.org/snippet/LOCKS-View-Locked-Objects_866.htm) to see what it locking the table then.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have run the query you gave me and returns no rows